# how can route form in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

My EventsController function is this in My Laravel app

```
public function storetask(Request $request, $id, Task $task)
    {
        $task = new Task;
        $task->task_name   = $request->input('name');
        $task->body = $request->input('body');
        $task->assign          = $request->input('status');
        $task->priority        = $request->input('status');
        $task->duedate  = $request->input('date');
        $task->project_id        = $id;

        $task->save();
}
```

I need save form data in My events folder show.blade.php file using above controller function
My form route is this

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('events.storetask') }}">
```

My route.php is this

```
Route::resource('events', 'EventsController');
```

but I got this error message

```
Route [events.storetask] not defined. (View: C:\Users\Flex\Desktop\kuruja\resources\views\events\show.blade.php)
```

how can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your route like below:

```
Route::post('/storeTask/{projectId}',array('uses'=>'EventsController@storetask','as'=>'storeTask'));
```

And call in your view

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('storeTask',$yourProjectId) }}">
```

Replace your controller function with the below function:

```
public function storetask($id=0)
{
        $task = new Task();
        $task->task_name    = \Input::get('name');
        $task->body         = \Input::get('body');
        $task->assign       = \Input::get('status');
        $task->priority     = \Input::get('status');
        $task->duedate      = \Input::get('date');
        $task->project_id   = $id;

        $task->save();
}
```

Comment: iam using here as storetask is it ok use as storeTask

Comment: error occured as Route [storetask] not defined. (View: C:\Users\Lilan\Desktop\conji\resources\views\events\show.blade.php)

Comment: Use `{{route('storeTask')}}`, no problem its the name of route that I defined

Comment: now new error Class App\Http\Controllers\EventsController does not exist

Comment: Then what is your controller name?

Comment: EventsController

Comment: Is your controller located at `App\Http\Controllers`?

Comment: Let me check your controller name and structure,

Comment: or friend it is letter mistake i fix this but now got new error Argument 3 passed to App\Http\Controllers\EventsController::storetask() must be an instance of App\Task, none given

Comment: OK, change your function as it was and remove my changes from your function

Answer (score 0):

You need a route for storetask.  When you use resource it creates 7 routes you should have on your Events controller.  index, create, store, show, edit, update, destroy.  You could just direct your form to store or create storetask instead.

You can also use php artisan routes command to view all your routes and you can see there isn't one named storetask.

Comment: did you mean may i change My Route::resource('events', 'EventsController'); as I used storetask

Comment: you are using storetask, but you don't have a route defined for it.  so you can either add another route for storetask or you can use store instead, because store is already defined and included in the resource route you have already.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is here:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('events.storetask') }}">
```

As when you register a resourceful route to the controller like:

```
Route::resource('photo', 'PhotoController');
```

This single route declaration creates multiple routes to handle a variety of RESTful actions on the photo resource. Likewise, the generated controller will already have methods stubbed for each of these actions, including notes informing you which URIs and verbs they handle.

Actions Handled By Resource Controller

```
Verb    Path    Action  Route Name
GET /photo  index   photo.index
GET /photo/create   create  photo.create
POST    /photo  store   photo.store
GET /photo/{photo}  show    photo.show
GET /photo/{photo}/edit edit    photo.edit
PUT/PATCH   /photo/{photo}  update  photo.update
DELETE  /photo/{photo}  destroy photo.destroy
```

but in your case the the method `storetask` do not match with the above list. So change the name according to the list and try again.

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)